# How to init Google Cloud Storage NodeJS client library with service account credentials

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-authentication

So I have the service account credentials json (as a string, or json object in my code):

```
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "myproject",
  "private_key_id": "lkjshdjhskas",
  //.... etc
}
```

and then I have this simple Cloud Storage upload snippet:

```
const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');

const creds = {service_account_object:"creds are here"};

const storage = new Storage();

const bucketName = 'my-bucket';
const filename = 'my-file.txt';

storage.bucket(bucketName).upload(filename, {
  gzip: true,
  metadata: {
    cacheControl: 'public, max-age=31536000',
  },
});
```

This is gives me an invalid_grant error, of course:

```
(node:15920) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: invalid_grant
    at Gaxios.request (C:\Users\Yuri\Documents\Code\btests\node_modules\gaxios\build\src\gaxios.js:70:23)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
(node:15920) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:15920) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I tried providing the creds as a param to the `Storage()` constructor, lie this `Storage(creds)` or even `Storage(JSON.stringify(creds))` but it just gives me weird errors.

**How do instantiate a Google client library object with service account credentials**?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The credentials data should be passed in the `credentials` property of the [StorageOptions](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/global.html#StorageOptions) object that you pass to the constructor:

```
const creds = {
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "myproject",
  "private_key_id": "lkjshdjhskas",
  //.... etc
}

const storage = new Storage({
  credentials: creds
});
```

Definitely familiarize yourself with the linked API docs, as they will explain how to use the APIs.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with the great answer of *Doug Stevenson*. 3 extra points worth mentioning:

**Use environment variable**

You may want to use `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable instead of copy the credentials file content into your code. Please consider to configure this environment variable as followed:

```
GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=YOUR_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CREDENTIALS_FILE.json
```

Where `YOUR_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CREDENTIALS_FILE` should be the same as the credentials file name. This way your storage c`tor will be empty

```
const storage = new Storage();  // this works when GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS is properly configured
```

If you are not sure how to produce this file, please follow the rest of this answer

**Generate your service account key**

1. Go to `GCP console` and choose from main menu `IAM & Admin` > `Service Accounts`
2. Select the relevant service account OR create a new one (*recommendation:* create different service accounts for different environments such as `dev`, `staging`, `prod`, etc.)
3. Select `Keys` tab and press the `Add Key` button
4. Select `json` as the required format
5. A credentials file should be automatically downloaded to your default downloads folder

**Set relevant storage permissions**

Without proper permissions your service account won't be able to do anything related to your storage. Configure permissions properly by following these steps:

1. Go to `GCP console` and navigate to `Cloud Storage`
2. Select your bucket
3. Go to `Permissions` tab and click the `Grant Access` button
4. Fill-in the full name of your service account under the `Add Principals` section
5. Add relevant roles (*recommendation:* filter roles by searching for `storage object` and select both `Storage Object Viewer` and `Storage Object Creator`)